# calling a dataframe column name in the parameters of a function

Tags: python, function, parameters

I have a dataframe with 8 columns that i would like to run below code (i tested it works on a single column) as a function to map/apply over all 8 columns.
[click here for sample of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tetL0.png)

```
all_adj_noun = []
for i in range(len(bigram_df)):
    if len([bigram_df['adj_noun'][i]]) >= 1:
        for j in range(len(bigram_df['adj_noun'][i])):
            all_adj_noun.append(bigram_df['adj_noun'][i][j])
```

However, when i tried to define function the code returns an empty list when it is not empty.

```
def combine_bigrams(df_name, col_name):
    all_bigrams = []
    for i in range(len(df_name)):
        if len([df_name[col_name][i]]) >= 1:
            for j in range(len(df_name[col_name][i])):
                return all_bigrams.append(df_name[col_name][i][j])
```

I call the function by

```
combine_bigrams(bigram_df, 'adj_noun')
```

May I know is there anything that I may be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning the result of `.append`, which is `None`

However, there is a better (and faster) way to do this. To return a list with all the values present in the columns, you can leverage [`Series.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html):

```
col_name = 'adj_noun'
all_bigrams = bigram_df[col_name].agg(sum)
```